# Why am I getting a render error while displaying Markers on Map in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to display Markers on the maps using <MapView.Markers> but I have been getting the render error like showing in the image. [image]

So,I am able to display the Map with the zoomed location of any city that i search but when i try to add markers for the available restaurants on the Map I get render error as shown in the image. Below is my code of the **map.screen.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Search } from "../components/search.component";
import { LocationContext } from "../../../services/location/location.context";
import { RestaurantsContext } from "../../../services/restaurants/restaurant.context";

const Map = styled(MapView)`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
`;

export const MapScreen = () => {
  const { location } = useContext(LocationContext);
  const { restaurants = [] } = useContext(RestaurantsContext);

  const [latDelta, setLatDelta] = useState(0);

  const { lat, lng, viewport } = location;

  useEffect(() => {
    const northeastLat = viewport.northeast.lat;
    const southwestLat = viewport.southwest.lat;

    setLatDelta(northeastLat - southwestLat);
  }, [location, viewport]);

  return (
    <>
      <Search />
      <Map
        region={{
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lng,
          latitudeDelta: latDelta,
          longitudeDelta: 0.02,
        }}
      >
        {restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
          return (
            <MapView.Marker
              key={restaurant.name}
              title={restaurant.name}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: restaurant.geometry.location.lat,
                longitude: restaurant.geometry.location.lng,
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Map>
    </>
  );
};
```